# wpf Double Column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I want to bind a data table on a data grid view in c# using wpf.

I bind it successfully, but the problem is, that i want to bind a column as Rowheader. This column is now double.

```
sda.Fill(dt);
            if (isPaddock)
            {
                dt.Columns["Paddock1"].ColumnName = "Paddock 1";
                dt.Columns["Paddock2"].ColumnName = "Paddock 2";
                dt.Columns["Paddock3"].ColumnName = "Paddock 3";
                dt.Columns["Paddock4"].ColumnName = "Paddock 4";
                dt.Columns["Paddock5"].ColumnName = "Paddock 5";
            }
            buchungDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

 <DataGrid Background="LightGray" RowBackground="LightYellow" MouseLeftButtonUp="buchungDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" x:Name="buchungDataGrid" RowHeight="70" CanUserReorderColumns="False" FontSize="20" Margin="20,20,0,0" CanUserResizeColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" FrozenColumnCount="1" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" ClipboardCopyMode="None" EnableRowVirtualization="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                <Setter Property= "Content"  Value="{Binding Uhrzeit}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

but the result is that the "Uhrzeit" column is a normal column and the row header column.

I tried to remove the column, make it invisible, but i don't get how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datagrid is going to auto generate all columns unless you set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, but that would mean you need to specify each column explicitly.

Alternately, you can attach to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and put logic there to stop specific columns from being included.

At my company, we have subclassed the datagrid class and override the `OnautoGeneratingColumn` function. We added a Dependancy Property of a csv list of column names to skip that can be set in the xaml. In `OnautoGeneratingColumn` we check that list of columns to skip.